# Check if Chromecast can play video file

Tags: android, video, mime-types, video-processing, chromecast

Our customers can upload videos to our servers, when they download our Android application they can play the videos amongst other features. One of them other features is being able to cast these videos to chromecast devices. When they tap to play a video our server sends over a url similar to:

> https://xxxxx.net/dl/standard-user/xxx/video-xxx?mime=true

At the moment we are using LocalCast to stream the content to a chromecast, but we get the error:

> This CheomeCast device does not support the video or cant access it.

We can definitely access it because our server only keeps healthy/working links. We want to add something into our code to see if the video is playable on ChromeCast if it is not playable on ChromeCast then we want to grey out the cast button for that particular video.

How would we check to see if the video is playable on ChromeCast? Client side that is. We want to check once the video url has been passed to the device.

We have searched online and searched Googles official documentation but cant seem to find enough information to solve the problem

Thanks all

Comment: Anybody able to provide any insight?